# meaning of the verb 工夫 in this example

Tags: translation, meaning, usage

What is the meaning of the verb 工夫 when it is used with clothes?

Example:

> [裏地]{うらじ}を[工夫]{くふう}してみる

Answer (score 2, accepted):

工夫する means "exercise ingenuity". If you use 工夫する for clothes, it is used, for example, when you add pockets, or when you change the backing cloth to a warmer material.