# Meaning of 工夫をこらす

Tags: meaning, set-phrases

Regarding decorations at a 七夕 festival:

> 道の両側には、**工夫をこらした**飾りがぶらさがっていた。
>   On both sides of the street ??? decorations were hanging.

I can't understand what 工夫をこらした means. 
I saw [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32932/meaning-of-the-verb-%E5%B7%A5%E5%A4%AB-in-this-example). Perhaps the meaning is similar?
Maybe, "Decorations of ingenious design"??

Is this a set phrase or can I understand the meaning from the separate parts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular context, I would use "***elaborate***" over anything else.

"elaborate decorations", "elaborate ornaments", etc.

The essential meaning of 「工夫をこらした」 is "not simple or plain".

To me at least, "ingenious" would be too big a word for this.